# Comparing two maps with nice web interface?

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, leaflet, swipe

Is it possible in Leaflet or OpenLayers to compare two maps with a bar to slide between the two?

Examples include:

- <s>http://www.esri.com/services/disaster-response/hurricanes/hurricane-sandy-the-aftermap</s>
- http://www.arcgis.com/apps/StorytellingSwipe/index.html?appid=c62112f6ba834227978d8f1cf2b6f5af
- http://www.abc.net.au/news/specials/qld-floods/ (not a map)

I know it's possible, I don't know how to do it though. Anyone got any ideas? Examples?

Comment: the Hurricane Sandy link seems to be dead now. Is [this](http://www.arcgis.com/apps/StorytellingSwipe/index.html?appid=c62112f6ba834227978d8f1cf2b6f5af) a better link to demonstrate the idea?

Comment: That works, I'll replace the other link @StephenLead

Answer (score 12):

What you want to do, is usually called a 'Swipe' tool.

There is no inbuilt tool or control for this in OpenLayers, but thankfully, there is an example here: [Swipe Control with Google and OSM](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/bjornharrtell/swipe/examples/swipe.html)  based on a custom class.

You just need to include [this](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/2886) JavaScript file in your application.

Most Swipe Tools/controls that I have seen online, are based on the simple CSS clip. It is very simple to integrate this kind of Control in your application even without external patches.

Comment: Seen anyone do it with Leaflet?

Comment: @alexgleith Have a look at this:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/leaflet-js/vXU_bir6JsA/2aEpOU7XGvQJ

Answer (score 8):

[Mango](http://www.mangomap.com) does it with Leaflet. Check out an [example here](http://mangomap.com/maps/20604/Deforestation-in-Cambodia-Between-1976---2013#).

Of course you could just save the time to code it yourself and just create the map for free using Mango.

Comment: That's a nice looking interface! But there's no reusable code there... I want something that is internal to our organisation, and I have already got infrastructure in place for styling and hosting data.

Answer (score 3):

This is a working Leaflet example using two WMS layers and leaflet 0.5. It does need a bit of tweaking, for example the layers aren't clipped while panning. But it works pretty well.

See here: https://github.com/gccgisteam/leaflet-examples/blob/master/leafletSwipe.html

Comment: I don't know if you are the author, but I'll give you two suggestions: Firstly using the Move event rather then the MoveEnd event gives real time swiping & secondly, I feel this is the opposite way of how a tool should be used. Instead of dragging the map, the slider should be dragged.

Comment: I actually like having both the slider at the bottom and the on mouse move. It means that with a mouse you get it working all the time, and with touch, you can still do it. I only just got it together, it is a proof of concept only. I'm sure there are a lot of options.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [WMS Split](https://github.com/icetan/wms-split) for Leaflet.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible with leaflet. here what I done the swipe map with leaflet and jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var currentX = $("#viewport").width() / 2;
        var resetPosition = function(x){
            var pos = $(".leaflet-map-pane").position(),
            coordLeft = ( - pos.top ) + "px, " + ( x - pos.left + 3 ) + "px, " + ( $("#viewport").height() - pos.top ) + "px, " + -pos.left + "px",
            coordRight = ( - pos.top ) + "px, " + ( $("#viewport").width() - pos.left ) + "px, " + ( $("#viewport").height() - pos.top ) + "px, " + ( x - pos.left + 3 ) + "px";
            $(".leaflet-layer:nth-child(3)").css("clip", "rect(" + coordLeft + ")");
            $(".leaflet-layer:nth-child(2)").css("clip", "rect(" + coordRight + ")");
        };
        resetPosition(currentX);
        map.on("move", function(){
            resetPosition(currentX);
        })
        map.on("zoomend", function(){
            resetPosition(currentX);
        });
        if( $.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) < 9 ){
            $("#vbar-divider").draggable({
                drag: function(e){
                    currentX = $("#vbar-divider").position().left;
                    resetPosition(currentX);
                },
                axis: "x"
            });
        }else{
            $("#vbar-divider").draggable({
                drag: function(e){
                    currentX = $("#vbar-divider").position().left;
                    resetPosition(currentX);
                    $("#vbar-divider div").hide();
                },
                stop: function(){
                    $("#vbar-divider div").show();
                },
                axis: "x",
                containment: "parent"
            });
        }
        $('#vbar-divider').animate({
                left: currentX,
            }, 
            500 
        );
    });
```

Comment: Have you got a complete example? How do you set up the two maps to swipe between?

Comment: you don't need two maps, what you need is one map with two layers, $(".leaflet-layer:nth-child(3)").css("clip", "rect(" + coordLeft + ")");
            $(".leaflet-layer:nth-child(2)").css("clip", "rect(" + coordRight + ")");

Comment: Ok, where (2) and (3) refer to layers 2 and 3 in order of adding to map?

Comment: the above code is up and running, what you need first is create a map and add two layers, then with jquery you can get the container of top layer and second top layer. using "css" clip to clip the two containers accordingly

Comment: Ok, so I have a naive implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ah6Bx/ what is missing?

Comment: Just bumping this. Any ideas why the jsfiddle doesn't work? Is it the version of JQuery I'm using?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look into OpenLayers 3. You can look at the code of examples by using CTRL + U: The code does not look too complex either:

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/examples/layer-swipe.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using a nice Openlayers 3 and 4 extensions by viglino. You can find the examples of Swipe tool and Synchronized maps here.

http://viglino.github.io/ol3-ext/examples/map.control.swipe.html

http://viglino.github.io/ol3-ext/examples/map.interaction.synchronize.html

His GitHub repository is located here: https://github.com/Viglino/ol3-ext

Those examples are included in the GitHub repository.