# what is the basic programming language or code language for raster swipe tool?

Tags: openlayers-2, erdas-imagine, swipe

How to develop a Swipe tool for rasters or vectors (Spatial layer) like openlayers or ErdasImagine. Can any one give me the references please

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should only be one question per question and by asking the same question for multiple products this is effectively multiple questions.

Answer (score 3):

In OpenLayers Swipe Control is easy enough to use, the following code should set you up:

```
var map;
var swipe;

function init() {

    map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div : "map",
        allOverlays : true
    });

    var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets");

    map.addLayers([ osm, gmap ]);

    swipe = new OpenLayers.Control.Swipe(osm);

    map.addControl(swipe);

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(10.2, 48.9).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()), 9);
}

function toggleControl(element) {
    if (element.checked) {
        swipe.activate();
    } else {
        swipe.deactivate();
    }
}
```

Another example of swipe control in OpenLayers is [this](http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL212/SwipeControl/SwipeControl_with_OL212_DGK5.asp), and [this](https://github.com/Landgate/slip-code-samples/blob/master/examples/wms/openlayers2-swipe.html).

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58231/comparing-two-maps-with-nice-web-interface) question is also a bit similar.

Comment: what is the function code for swipe.active() and swipe.deactive() ?